# Request additional open graph action properties after approval

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

Is there any way to resubmit an open graph action for further permissions after it has been accepted?

For example, trying to post a message property with the action returns the following error:

`{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"This action is not allowed to set a user message because this property was not requested for approval."}}`

Can you change this or is the only solution to delete the action and re-apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (May 2012) you need to delete and reapply, i believe there's plans to make it so you can request the three further permissions separately after approval of the initial action, but right now it can't be edited after approval